# Nginx configuration:files alias

Tags: nginx

Here is the part of nginx config that doesn t work. Code s got from [there](http://blog.bripkens.de/2012/03/nginx-cache-busting/)

```
location ~* ^/static/(\w+)/([^/]+)_\d+\.(js|css)$ {
        alias /home/user_name/htdocs/site_name/static/$1/$2.$3;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        expires max;
 }
```

I cant figure out why server doesn t want to process url like

```
> http://site_name/static/css/site_1400842165.css?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your location string is the ^ at the beginning of the regex.  Your site routing is a little different than the example then the example the author was using in their blog; they were using static/ as the top level of their URL.  You could remove the ^, or do something more specific like:

```
^(http:|https:)//(\w+)/static/(\w+)/([^/]+)_\d+\.(js|css)
```

Or if you know the top level folder will always be the same, then you could replace the first "(\w+)" with the top level folder name.  Depends on how exactly your server is set up.